# Unconfirmed Transaction - 8days - Exchange to Hardwallet

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

Hi All I transferred BTC from exchange (BTC Markets) to Ledger Nano. Transaction after 8 days still showing up as unconfirmed however the amount shows up in the wallet. Any suggestions or clarity on this?

Comment: Have you contacted Ledger support; they are pretty good. Tweet them and they normally respond

Comment: @talesfromtheCRYPT: The Ledger wallet is merely the recipient here, they are not at fault, and I don't see how they would be in a special position to help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest contacting BTC Markets and asking them to increase the transaction fee. Ledger isn't the issue - most wallets display unconfirmed transactions.